# upsert stored procedure using merge + select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm following the below approach to perform Upsert operation. The problem is that I also need to perform a select in order to get an uniqueidentifier that should be used in the insert statement.

It seems that this select needs to be at the USING part right below the MERGe line, however I can't find a way to work with both (the select / the provided parameter type)

current

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spUpsertEmployee @employee EmployeeType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  MERGE employee AS target_sqldb
  USING @employee AS source_tblstg
  ON (target_sqldb.employee_id = source_tblstg.RowKey)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET 
      department = source_tblstg.PartitionKey,
      first_name = source_tblstg.FirstName,
      last_name = source_tblstg.LastName,
      gender = source_tblstg.Gender,
      role = source_tblstg.Role
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (
          employee_id,
          department,
          first_name,
          last_name,
          gender,
          role
        )
      VALUES (
          source_tblstg.RowKey,
          source_tblstg.PartitionKey,
          source_tblstg.FirstName,
          source_tblstg.LastName,
          source_tblstg.Gender,
          source_tblstg.Role
        );
END
```

desired

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spUpsertEmployee @employee EmployeeType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  MERGE employee AS target_sqldb
  USING @employee AS source_tblstg
  ON (target_sqldb.employee_id = source_tblstg.RowKey)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET 
      department = source_tblstg.PartitionKey,
      first_name = source_tblstg.FirstName,
      last_name = source_tblstg.LastName,
      gender = source_tblstg.Gender,
      role = source_tblstg.Role
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (
          employee_id,
          department,
          id,
          first_name,
          last_name,
          gender,
          role
        )
      VALUES (
          source_tblstg.RowKey,
          source_tblstg.PartitionKey,
          (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM OTHER_TABLE),
          source_tblstg.FirstName,
          source_tblstg.LastName,
          source_tblstg.Gender,
          source_tblstg.Role
        );
END
```

Comment: Can you `merge` the result of a CTE that contains an `outer join` to pick up the needed unique identifier?

Comment: what I need is to perform a select and get an unique id from another table (only for the insert statement) is it possible using the current solution?

Comment: You can pick up extra input columns by using `with SourceCTE as ( select *, ( select top 1 Id from Other_Table ) as InsertId from @Employee ) merge ... using SourceCTE ...;`. That will apply _one_ `Id` to _all_ of the inserted rows. Is that really what you want?